# Django How about my method to solve anti spam post request? Is there better solutions?

Tags: python, django

I have little experience with this kind of job, I can't find an app that suits my needs well. So I have to write my own code. But I don't know whether there is a better way, this is why I am here.

I know this app `django-simple-captcha`, it is good but not enough because I want to do a more reasonable job, that is, I don't want bother normal user to fill captcha fields. What I want is: if a user send post requests more than `ALLOW_TIMES` within the `CHECK_SECONDS` I defined, the `request.is_attack` will be True, and I will know to render a django-simple-captcha form instead of the normal form.

I tried this method, using a custom Middleware: I record a user's each post request infomation in a global dict to decide the value of request.is_attack.

```
import datetime

datetime_now = datetime.datetime.now
USER_POST_INFO={}
CHECK_SECONDS=60
ALLOW_TIMES=3

class AntiAttackMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        '''
        if this user send more than ALLOW_TIMES request
        in CHECK_SECONDS, set request.is_attack to True,
        otherwise False
        '''
        user = request.user
        if request.method == "POST" and user.is_authenticated():
            now = datetime_now()
            if user.pk not in USER_POST_INFO:
                USER_POST_INFO[user.pk]={
                    'time':now,
                    'total':1,
                    'attack':False,
                }
                request.is_attack=False
            else:
                d = USER_POST_INFO[user.pk]
                if d['time'] + datetime.timedelta(seconds=CHECK_SECONDS) > now :
                    d['total'] +=1
                    if d['total']>ALLOW_TIMES:
                        d['attack']=True
                else:
                    d['time']=now
                    d['attack']=False
                request.is_attack=d['attack']
```

In views.py

```
def formview(request):
    if request.is_attack:
        #render captcha form
    else:
        #render normal form
```

Comment: u can use https://github.com/ui/django-anti_spam be useful if u browse there code n get an overview :)

Comment: @Sundar Nataraj Thank you , too:)